# Build android aar file with only command-line tools

Tags: android, android-library

Is there any way to build and use an android library (aar file) without Android Studio and without Gradle, only using android command-line tools?

Comment: Why do you exclude gradle from "Android command-line" tools? Gradle is designed to build exactly the way you are asking for.

Comment: Because it does some magic behind the scenes, and is this magic I want to know.

Comment: gradle and the android-gradle-plugin don't use magic. A basic overview how it works is [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build). And for gradle you can view the detailed log if you add `-d` to gradle. And if you want to know more details look at the source of https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to find what I want there.